# stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to tcp://gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, smtp

stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to tcp://gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25

```
 stream_socket_client("tcp://gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25", $errno, $errstr, 30)
```

**ufw status**
root@XXXXX:~# sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From

---

Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTPS                ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       00.000.000.000
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
53                         ALLOW       Anywhere
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
25                         ALLOW       Anywhere
23/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx HTTPS (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
53 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
23/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

25/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)

Comment: In short: access to port 25 is likely blocked by your hosting provider to prevent sending spam. For sending mail you normally should not try to send unauthenticated mail directly to the MX of the domain  but use an account at your mail provider instead.

Comment: I was going to say...why are you trying to create a raw socket connection to the SMTP server anyway??

Comment: P.S. Anyway it's likely these ufw rules show rules about _incoming_ connections. That has nothing to do with whether you can make an _outgoing_ connection on any of these ports. Use `sudo ufw status verbose` to see all rules and check whether they are inbound or outbound (ref: https://linuxhint.com/ufw_list_rules/)